# Libvirt Python SSH connection timeout

Tags: python, libvirt

I am developing a frontend for libvirt in Python and I'm using SSH as transport.

```py
self.conn = libvirt.open("qemu+ssh://root@%s/system?no_tty=1" % node)
```

Is there a way to set connection timeout within libvirt? I checked docs and found no such thing, which leads me to believe I need to modify libvirt lib itself?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no way to set the SSH connection timeout in libvirt, it will just use the default in SSH, unless your $HOME/.ssh/config has overridden it.

Comment: I would add that it is probably not very difficult to enhance libvirt to support this. It would be a matter of accepting an "timeout=XX" parameter in the URI string & passing the right option to the SSH command libvirt supports.  So if you want to look at writing a patch, the libvirt project would be happy to accept it as a feature.